# Why are my object keys undefined and the values are not

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this simple object array being built

```
var myData = $('.form-group input:not(.add), .form-group select').map(function() {
    return {
        'id': this.id,
        'value': this.value
    };
}).get();
```

If I console.log the output I can see the keys and the values

but as soon as I try to use `myData` in an $.ajax call, it drops the keys?

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: site + form,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: myData,
    success: function(response) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

This is the POST headers:

[image: console log]

Comment: can you post the console log

Comment: @chiliNUT - done, or did you want actual headers?

Comment: i suggest drop the async false then try passing `JSON.stringify(myData)` you can later do `json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myData']), true);` in url pagethe

Comment: @guradio - using `JSON.stringify(myData)` I can see all the keys and values in there even from within the ajax call `[{"id":"skillAreas","value":"1"},{"id":"skillGroupName","value":"dhdh"}]` just for some reason if I call just 'myData' it won't return the keys??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting data your data should look like:

```
{
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2
}
```

In your case, your data looked like:

```
[
    {
        id: key1,
        value: val1
     },
     {
        id: key1,
        value: val1
     }
]
```

Here is a fix for how to build your `myData` variable:

```js
var myData = {}
$('select').each(function() {
    myData[this.id] = this.value;
})

console.log(myData)
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: myData,
    success: function(response) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="a"><option>1</option></select>

<select id="b"><option>2</option></select>
```